# new register laravel 5 (eloquent)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to make a record after validation of data sent with ajax. the idea is to run the function CreateNewUser if no errors, but does not store the data in the DB. that will happen this?

Thank you.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Modals\NewUser;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
    public function NewUser(Request $request)
    {
        $validator= Validator::make($request->all(),[

            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:8|same:cpassword',
            'cpassword'=> 'required',

        ]);

        if($validator->fails()){
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'error' => $validator->errors()->toArray()
            ]);


        }else{
            return response()->json(['success' => true ]);

            $this->CreateNewUser($request);
        }

    }

    private function CreateNewUser(Request $requestt){

        $user = new NewUser;
        $user->name = $requestt->name;
        $user->email = $requestt->email;
        $user->passwosrd = $requestt->password;
        $user->rememberToken = $requestt->_token;
        $user->save();
    }


}
```

model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Modals;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class NewUser extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';
}
```

js:

```
function send(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({


        type: 'post',
        url: userAjax,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            email: $('#correo').val(),
            password: $('#password').val(),
            cpassword: $('#cpassword').val(),
            _token: $('#new-user').attr('data-token')
        },
        beforeSend: function()
        {
            $("#nameError").fadeOut();
            $("#emailError").fadeOut();
            $("#passwordError").fadeOut();
            $("#cpasswordError").fadeOut();

        },

        success: function(data){



           if(!data.success){
               console.log(data);
               if(typeof data.error.name !== 'undefined'){

                   $('#name').css('border-color', 'red');
                   $('#nameError').fadeIn(10, function () {
                       $("#nameError").html(data.error.name);

                   })
               }
               if(typeof data.error.email !== 'undefined'){
                   $('#correo').css('border-color', 'red');
                   $('#emailError').fadeIn(10, function () {
                       $("#emailError").html(data.error.email);

                   })
               }
               if(typeof data.error.password !== 'undefined'){
                   $('#password').css('border-color', 'red');
                   $('#passwordError').fadeIn(10, function () {
                       $("#passwordError").html(data.error.password[0]);


                   })
               }
               if(typeof data.error.cpassword !== 'undefined'){
                   $('#cpassword').css('border-color', 'red');
                   $('#cpasswordError').fadeIn(10, function () {
                       $("#cpasswordError").html(data.error.cpassword);


                   })
               }


            }else{
               console.log(data);
               $('#Register').modal('hide');
               $("#header").replaceWith($('#header'));
            }

        },
        error: function() {}

    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In you code you are returning the JSON response and then you are trying to execute the create function and will, it should be the other way:

How it is in your code:

```
return response()->json(['success' => true ]);
$this->CreateNewUser($request);
```

How it should be:

```
$this->CreateNewUser($request);
return response()->json(['success' => true ]);
```

You could also do this:

```
if($this->CreateNewUser($request)){
    return response()->json(['success' => true ]);
}else{
    return response()->json(['success' => false ]);
}
```

Also try changing your CreateNewUser function to this:

```
   private function CreateNewUser(Request $requestt){

    $user = new NewUser(); // was $user = new NewUser();
    $user->name = $requestt->name;
    $user->email = $requestt->email;
    $user->password = $requestt->password; // was $user->passwosrd = $requestt->password
    $user->rememberToken = $requestt->_token;
    $user->save();
}
```

Comment: did you change the order of the first two lines I mentioned? @RecoJhonatan

Comment: yes, Yes, I changed the order of execution in the else, and still does not work, and too the lines in the function CreateNewUser  @mkmnstr

Comment: Thats all what comes to me. I need more information. If you did the changes I pointed it should work perfectly. Any error showing or just not recording?

Comment: just not recording

Comment: what is the JSON response you get? also, where is NewUser being called?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114670/discussion-between-reco-jhonatan-and-mkmnstr).